# Pine Script / Capturing values from bars with a condition to latest bar into a series

Tags: pine-script

The following code marks all bars where `a bar's high > high at the last bar` with a vertical line. Is there a way to capture all these values as a series so that they have their respective high values where this condition is true and otherwise `na`?

```
//@version=4
study(title="Bars above last high", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)

lookbackPeriod = input(500, title="Lookback Period", minval=2, step=100)

if barstate.islast 
    for idx = 0 to lookbackPeriod - 1
        if high[idx] > high 
            line.new(x1=bar_index[idx], y1=low[idx], x2=bar_index[idx], y2=low[idx] * 0.9995, 
                 color=color.orange, width=2, extend=extend.both)
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in Pine.
Reason is that a script is executed on every bar, starting from the oldest bar up until the current bar.
That means that you cannot know the `high` of the most recent bar, until you get there.
Just like in the real world, Pine cannot look into the future.

If you really wanted to, you could create a series of all the highs like this:

```
var float myHighs = na
myHighs := high
```

Then, on `barstate.islast` you could loop over the elements to make them `na` where the condition is `false`. But that would be futile, as there's no use for that series.
By the time you've completed your series, you're also at the most recent bar.
So you wouldn't be able to `plot()` that series.

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish really.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of the values you need. 
 BUT this array will ONLY be available for processing on the LAST bar. 
 Only the `line` and `label` objects can be used to display charts on historical bars.